# jQuery - one of the two divs open onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My jquery should open only the first of two divs on page load, but now it opens both.

Also, I've added `.active` class to my CSS to color the active divs link, but it won't work.

### Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideDown();
 });
 $('.infoexpanderHead').click(function () {
     $(this).siblings().find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
     $(this).find('#infoactive').addClass("active");
     $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideDown();
     $(this).siblings().find('#infoactive').removeClass("active");
 });
```

### CSS

```
.active {
    color: green;
}
```

Really new to JS and Jquery so be simple please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$('.infoexpanderContent:first').slideDown();
```

By the way, there's no need for the `$(this).find()` method, since in the DOM wrapper, `$(this)` refers to the document, which is always assumed in jQuery.

Comment: Isn't the method .first() faster ?

Comment: Works for me just as intended.

Comment: @Virus721 depends upon the context ideally. The fastest I think would be `eq(0)`. Anyway, for a single element it shouldn't make too much of an issue in the given context.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the dom ready handler `this` refers to the document object so your selector `$(this).find('.infoexpanderContent')` returns all `infoexpanderContent` elements in the page and slides them down

Fire the click event on the first element after the click handler is added

```
$('.infoexpanderHead').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
    $(this).find('#infoactive').addClass("active");
    $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideDown();
    $(this).siblings().find('#infoactive').removeClass("active");
}).first().click();
```

It is better to use a manual click trigger since you also will have to add the active class to the first `infoactive` element